# Nuxt plugin not available in Vuex's 'this' in Firebase production (ERROR: this.$myPlugin is not a function)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm trying to upload my `nuxt` app to `Firebase` as cloud function. The problem is that in the `nuxtServerInit` action I'm trying to call a `plugin` function, which apparently is not yet defined at that moment, because an error is thrown: `(ERROR: this.$myPlugin is not a function)`. The code **works in dev mode**, it's just after upload to `Firebase` it fails.

The setup is as follows:

**myPlugin.js**

```js
let env, auth, app, $store;
export default (context, inject) => {
    env = context.app.context.env;
    auth = context.app.$fire.auth;
    app = context.app;
    $store = context.store;
    inject('myPlugin', myPlugin);
};
async function myPlugin(...) {... }
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/myPlugin', mode: 'all' }, // with no mode specified it fails too
],
```

**vuex index.js**

```js
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit }, { req }) { 
        const tl = await dispatch("initAction");
        return tl;
    }
}
```

**vuex someModule.js**

```js
const actions = {
    initAction({ commit }) {
        return this.$myPlugin(...).then(...) // this line throws '$myPlugin is not a function' error
    }
}
```

What can be the reason for the different behaviour in `dev` and in `prod` modes and how could I fix the problem?

UPDATE:
After further testing I established that the problem is not caused by the `nuxtServerInit` timing. I moved the call of the `initAction` from `nuxtServerInit` to a page's `created` hook. However the same error appears: `this.$query is not a function`.

Comment: Can you check if the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391182/vuex-this-store-dispatch-is-not-a-function/62393976#62393976) helps you? Also can you check if you declared all the dependencies correctly to firestore like in  dev env.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I have some different problem than mentioned in that thread. Regarding declaring correctly all dependencies to firestore, then IDK what dependencies should be declared differently for firestore prod than dev? And how that would prevent from getting plugin registered? There's one default line in `nuxt.config.js` that `nuxt` docs don't explain which is `chunkName: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'firebase-auth' : '[id]'`. Should I modify it in any way?

Comment: Can you please provide the application logs if it is possible?

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem in the meantime, it was caused by CORB errors preventing js files to load properly. I updated the question with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occured, because js files were not getting fully loaded due to CORB errors caused by incorrect configuration. Details described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496721/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb-blocks-scripts-and-images-loading-for-nuxt-app).