# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocks scripts and images loading for Nuxt app deployed as Firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I uploaded a `Nuxt` app as Firebase cloud function. When I access the app it gets loaded only partially, and a bunch of Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) gets displayed in the console.
The errors relate to images and scripts stored in the `public` folder and requested in the `HTML` that is rendered as cloud function's response. Example of what causes the issue:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/90bbcfe.js" as="script">
```

[Link to the app](https://us-central1-turniejomat.cloudfunctions.net/turniejomat#), so you can see the error in 'real world'. Sometimes error `Could not handle the request` appears instead of the page, so you might need to try a few times. If you know why this other error appears, I'm keen to know too.

How can I make it work?

Comment: can you please provide us the steps using which you deployed. And if possible can you please provide any logs related to that? Also CORS configuration you have in the public bucket, you should have something [like this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support),  maybe it was setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you exposed relies in the way nuxt generates and deploy the assets.
When you reach your cloud function endpoint, the function itself returns to the client a webpage, and the webpage asks the browser to load additional assets.

Let's pretend the asset is "_nuxt/90bbcfe.js", which is translated to this full URL: "https://us-central1-turniejomat.cloudfunctions.net/_nuxt/90bbcfe.js"

When the browser tries to load that resource, it expects to obtain a text/javascript or application/javascript as response, but got text/html instead, and thus the CORB: if you try to load a javascript source, but the server provides an HTML, the browser thinks something evil could harm your system and blocks the request.

Actually, the full url above redirects to a Google AppEngine HTML page, which asks you to login with google to use the application.

[image: See the resulting page]

I don't know if this login page is part of your application or not, but If you don't recognize that login page, I suspect you didn't **properly configured the firebase hosting** to redirect all the traffic to your function. An example could be found [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/firebase/deploy-nuxt-to-firebase-cloud-functions/)

However, If you don't need the SSR deploy option, I would suggest you to stop using Cloud Functions to host Nuxt WebApps, and start using the [generate](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/commands#static-deployment-pre-rendered) command to build a static pre-rendered webapp, and then upload it to Firebase Hosting, which is a CDN specifically designed for this tasks.

You could definitely keep using Cloud Functions as a backend for your webapplication.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was missing the `firebase functions:config:set nuxtssr.runtime_api_url="https://PROJECT.firebaseapp.com"` step. And also calling the cloud function url instead of project's url.